# Flutter slider is not reacting to dragging

Tags: flutter, dart, slider

I implemented Flutter Slider in my project, it's looking same as documentation, but slider is only reacting to click on one of division, when I tried to drag it and move it's not moving.

Here is my code:

```
Stack(
                                            alignment: AlignmentDirectional.topCenter,
                                            children: [
                                              Padding(
                                                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                                      horizontal: size.width * 0.05),
                                                  child: Slider(
                                                    max: 30,
                                                    min: 1,
                                                    divisions: 6,
                                                    activeColor: Theme.of(context)
                                                        .primaryColor,
                                                    label: helperDistance!
                                                            .floor()
                                                            .toString() + 'km',
                                                    value: helperDistance!,
                                                    onChanged: (newValue) {
                                                      print(newValue);
                                                      setState(() =>
                                                          helperDistance = newValue);
                                                    },
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                                AutoSizeText(helperDistance!.floor().toString() + ' km'),
                                            ],
                                          )
```

What is wrong actually here?

EDIT: I was using Flutter 3.0, upgrading Flutter to 3.0.5 solved the problem

Comment: convert your `StatelessWidget` into `StatefulWidget`

Comment: It's actually is `StatefulWidget`

Comment: for me it's working, what version of flutter do you use?

Comment: where had you defined the helperDistance variable.

Comment: @Develocode777 flutter 3.0

Comment: @MunsifAli on top of the class, that one which extends State<ClassName>

Comment: it is working correctly with us can you add more info or add the screen shot of your debug console

Comment: i Copied your code and it worked for me after with a little bit of change. and i created the variable helperDistance just above the build method... here is the code .Stack(
                alignment: AlignmentDirectional.topCenter,
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                    child: Slider(
                      max: 30,
                      min: 1,
                      divisions: 6,
                      activeColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                      label: helperDistance.flo

Comment: try updating to flutter 3.0.5, there was a similar bug in flutter 3.0.0

Comment: @Develocode777 Upgrading solved the problem, thanks

Comment: glad to have helped

Answer (score 0):

It is working correctly if your variable is in the build method int that case it wont work because the build method is called every time you call the setState method and the value of the variable becomes the default again. if that is the case move that variable above the build method and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, it was problem with Flutter 3.0, upgrading to 3.0.5 solved the problem.